# Security group creation leading to error in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a forensic infrastructure which should have a VPC, a `ForensicSecurityGroup` and an `IsolatedSecurityGroup`.
Inbound SSH into the `IsolatedSecurityGroup` should only be allowed from the `ForensicSecurityGroup`.

On running my template, following error gets reported when the `IsolatedSecurityGroup` is in creation.

```
You have specified two resources that belong to different networks. 
(Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; Request ID: 1581ea3a-b9ad-4b06-bdd7-518c9d710e5e; Proxy: null)
```

Here is how my template looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Template for immediately isolation and forensic investigation of compromised instances
Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  Ec2KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  PurposeTag:
    Type: String
    Default: forensics
  SSHLocation:
    Description: >-
      Enter desired Network CIDR to access EC2 instance. Default is set to
      access from anywhere and it is not recommended. Please change to appropriate
      CIDR.
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must be a valid Network CIDR of the form x.x.x.x/y. Default is set to
      0.0.0.0/0, in production do not set default to 0.0.0.0/0  

Mappings:
  ImageId:
    us-east-1:
      AmazonLinux2: ami-00dc79254d0461090
      UbuntuCanonical: ami-04b9e92b5572fa0d1
    us-east-2:
      AmazonLinux2: ami-00bf61217e296b409
      UbuntuCanonical: ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a
    us-west-1:
      AmazonLinux2: ami-024c80694b5b3e51a
      UbuntuCanonical: ami-0dd655843c87b6930
    us-west-2:
      AmazonLinux2: ami-0a85857bfc5345c38
      UbuntuCanonical: ami-06d51e91cea0dac8d
    eu-west-1:
      AmazonLinux2: ami-040ba9174949f6de4
      UbuntuCanonical: ami-02df9ea15c1778c9c

Resources:
  ForensicSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for forensic EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Allow SSH from company ip address
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
      Tags:
        - Key: Purpose
          Value: !Ref PurposeTag

  ForensicInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          commands:
            1_sift_download:
              command: "wget https://github.com/teamdfir/sift-cli/releases/download/v1.7.1/sift-cli-linux -P /tmp/"
            2_rename:
              command: "mv /tmp/sift-cli-linux /usr/local/bin/sift"
            3_sift_permissions:
              command: "chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/sift"
            4_sift_install:
              command: "/usr/local/bin/sift install"
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ForensicInstanceProfile
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - ImageId
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - UbuntuCanonical

      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref Ec2KeyName
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt ForensicSecurityGroup.GroupId
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt update
          apt -y install python-pip
          pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
          cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackName} --region ${AWS::Region} -r ForensicInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Purpose
          Value: !Ref PurposeTag

  ForensicInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref ForensicInstanceRole

  ForensicInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess

  IsolatedSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group that allows only SSH from the forensics group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Allow SSH
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt ForensicSecurityGroup.GroupId
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - Description: Limit outbound traffic to only localhost, removes the default quad-zero outbound rule
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      Tags:
        - Key: Purpose
          Value: !Ref PurposeTag
```

Can someone help me understand the cause of error here? Is this more like circular dependency or completely different?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify the VPCID for the ForensicSecurityGroup, therefore it will allocate in default VPC.

You should add
`VpcId: !Ref VpcId` to the `ForensicInstance`

Comment: It now failed at creating the Ec2 instance. The error says
```
Security group sg-0e983952a319deecf(`ForensicInstance`) and subnet subnet-0fb1a03979897974d belong to different networks. 
```

Comment: You need to make sure which VPC you want to put all the resources in. Your errors are about the you want to attach the SG of other VPC because SG is only in VPC. 
Just put all of them in 1 VPC, or you can remove the VpcId in the IsolatedSecurityGroup

Comment: @abhinavsingh The answer solved the issue reported, thus it should be accepted.